# Loop through several columns to create a new Variable

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable 0/1 if a condition is met in any of 15 columns.

So if comorbidity=10 in any of the columns (comorbidity1 to comorbidity15) then assign a 1 otherwise it is 0

```
comorbidity1 comorbidity2 ... comorbidity15
1.           42.          ... 10
34.          9.           ... 0
13.          10.          ... 0
10.          34.          ... 0
0.           0.           ... 0
0.           0.           ... 0
```

these columns are not next to each other in the data set. Therefore I am wondering if there is a way of looping through by specific column names?

I think the loop would look like this for variable

```
for (i in 1:nrow(fulldata){
 if(fulldata$comorbidity1[i]==10{
   fulldata$diabetespresent[i]<-1}
  else{fulldata$diabetespresent[i]<-0}}
```

I anticipate the data set would like

```
comorbidity1 comorbidity2 ... comorbidity15 Diabetes_present
1.           42.          ... 10.           1
34.          9.           ... 0.            0
13.          10.          ... 0.            1
10.          34.          ... 0.            1
11.          0.           ... 0.            0
4.           0.           ... 0.            0
```

Comment: Could you try this code `cols <- paste0("comorbidity", 1:15)     

df$Diabetes_present <- +apply(df[, cols], 1, function(x) any(x==10))
` and let me know if it works ?

Comment: I think that appears to work in assigning all the cases where x==10 but it doesn't list all the other cases as 0?

Comment: which other cases? can you provide an example for more clarity? (I'm not sure to understand the cases you refer to).

Comment: By cases I meant when x does not equal 10 I wanted it to return 0 but I have resolved this by assigning the na=0

Comment: Could this command be used for x==10 AND x==11 at the same time for example?

Comment: If you want to set NAs equal to 0 in the same code, you can use  `df$Diabetes_present <- +apply(df[, cols], 1, function(x) 10 %in% x)` which is likely simpler.

Comment: Note that x==10 AND x==11 is empty because x cannot be equal to 10 and 11 at the same time. Do you mean where x contains 10 or 11?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant x==10 or x==11

Comment: If you want to use more than one value (10 and 11 in your example), `df$Diabetes_present <- +apply(df[, cols], 1, function(x) any(c(10, 11) %in% x))` could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` on selected, non-contiguous columns.  I prefer to use column numbers as references rather than column names.  Here is a toy example using a randomly generated matrix:

```
set.seed(7)
x <- sample(c(10, 11, 1:20), 30, replace = TRUE)
m <- matrix(x, ncol = 5)

# only columns 1, 3, 5 are tested
test <- apply(m[ , c(1, 3, 5)], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x == 10 | x == 11), 1, 0))
[1] 1 1 0 1 0 0

#You can then cbind test to your data frame.  Here:
m2 <- cbind(m, test)
m2
                   test
[1,]  8  6 10  4  4    1
[2,] 17  1 17 14 11    1
[3,]  5  6 18 20  2    0
[4,] 11 20  6 19  4    1
[5,] 13 13 16  2  9    0
[6,] 20  6 13  9  6    0
```